# Webcam capture and convert to avi

Tags: c#, video, webcam, encode, divx

Im trying to make a program that captures a video from the webcam and sound from the microphone but im getting stuck at the part where ive try to make a movie out of still images

ive heard you need to use directshow but it doesnt jet work for me

Does someone know a good piece of example code that captures video and sound and can encode it to a file (divx or something like that) ?

or some suggestions where to look so i can build it myself

(if a other programming language is better for this im happy to know it early. )

Answer (score 3):

I believe AForge.net has video creation utilities built in. It might use DirectShow in the background. But I've used it for capturing a video stream, and I'm 90% sure it can be used for encoding video!

Find your binarys/source at:

http://www.aforgenet.com/

http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DirectShow.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx) ([Article](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)), which has many samples such as TV capture and encoding.