# Capture video using webcam and save as avi using c#

Tags: c#, webcam, video-capture, encode, avi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webcam capture and convert to avi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807040/webcam-capture-and-convert-to-avi)

Is there any way of capturing video from webcam, encode and save the video as an avi file (as a movie) using c#?

Comment: It's web or winform application?

Comment: you should have to describe your question..

Comment: Check out these links 1. [WebCam Fast Image Capture Service using WIA](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WebCamService.aspx) 2. [Programatic​allyUsing A ​Webcam In ​C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/93476-Programatically-Using-A-Webcam-In-C) 3. [How can I stream webcam video with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c)

Answer (score 4):

Use **[AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/)**. Well tested, well documented, well maintained.

> **[AForge.NET Framework](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)** is a C# framework designed for developers and
>   researchers in the fields of Computer
>   Vision and Artificial Intelligence -
>   image processing, neural networks,
>   genetic algorithms, machine learning,
>   robotics, etc.